# Is there a formal reason for identifying and using "knee/elbow points"?

Tags: optimization, threshold

I am trying to understand the reasoning behind identifying knee/elbow points as suitable thresholds.

From what my own intuition tells me, the use of a knee/elbow point is akin to determining an **optimal** point `A` of production quantity to minimise cost.

[image]

Here are some examples of knee/elbow points being selected as thresholds:

- In this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113191/in-a-bursty-dataset-how-do-you-filter-for-the-few-important-values-that-make/113214#113214), the OP asks how he can keep the data that represents the majority of the information while filtering out the noise.
- In this [article](https://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~barath/papers/kneedle-simplex11.pdf), the writer describes an algorithm for identifying knee/elbow points in running a large MapReduce job where the knee/elbow point is chosen as a threshold for speculatively re-executing processes in hopes that the MapReduce job would complete in a shorter time.

So in other words – what is the scientific reasoning behind selecting/identifying knee/elbow points?

Thanks!

Comment: "what's the deal about X" is too vague/broad. Please keep to specific questions. Your third paragraph is unclear -- who uses such points for that purpose? What do they actually say? Can you give an example - preferably a quote with some context? It's also not clear what such points in general have to do with production quantities, since functions with kinks in them are used in all manner of situations. In short, please edit to clarify and give context for your premises and clarify what it is you're really seeking. If you are reading something that is unclear to you, please quote it.

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry I didn't think it through a bit more. I have edited my question to include references/contexts. Hope it helps makes what i'm asking much more specific!

Comment: The image you show isn't of an "elbow" as I would understand the term. See the top image [here](https://janhove.github.io/analysis/2014/08/20/adjusted-pvalues-breakpoint-regression) for what I'd interpret the phrase to mean.. As for the answer mentioning a knee at the linked post, that's in a *very* specific context (finding the largest few data values that contain most of the total); [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7pTH.png) is the knee Aniko was referring to. When you get a knee, there's a marked change (reduction) ... ctd

Comment: ctd... in the rate of increase of contributions to the total (rather than a more gradual decay). The identification of knees in the linked article is trying to so something similar. Identification of kinks in cumulative calculations to see where a process is no longer contributing much is fairly common. Similarly, see the use of *scree plots* (e.g. in principal components analysis/factor analysis), which is looking for a marked change without doing the cumulating. But I'm not sure I'm getting at what you're after at all.

Comment: Hey Glen_b! Thanks for clarifying! I wanted to know if there's a scientific/statistical reason (e.g values below the knee point are 1 or 2 SDs away etc) why we identify knees/elbows. But I think your comments may have just answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition about optimization is right. The elbow/knee considered as the point where the independant variable(s) will either start to or cease having a larger effect on the dependant variable. In other words, when increasing the independant variable by one unit, the marginal increase/decrease on the dependant variable will suddenly become faster/slower. Why is that?

If you look at a typical case with logistic regression:
[image: graph example - log regression]

We are looking at the probability of success in a test based on the score in a pre-test. As you can see, it seems that somewhere between 80 and 90, the "return on investment" is not as large. The participants have a larger chance of success of course, but the increase in the probability when you increase the score by 1 point is not as large. We can assess that by looking at some pre-test scores and the associated probability of non failing the post-test:

```
Pre-test score    Prob (rounded)  Change (rounded)
60                0.257            --
61                0.281            0.024
62                0.306            0.025
63                0.332            0.026
...               ...              ...
```

I added a "Change" column that indicated the change in prob when score is increased by 1. As you can see the change is rather stable, which is coherent with what we see in the graph in that interval. But around 81, the change starts getting smaller then will stabilize at a lower value:

```
Pre-test score    Prob (rounded)  Change (rounded)
78                0.755            0.023
79                0.776            0.022
80                0.797            0.020
81                0.816            0.019
82                0.833            0.017
83                0.850            0.016
...               ...              ...
```

Now suppose that I'm a student preparing for the course, and let's suppose that the pre-test score is an indicator of the time spent studying. I should aim for about 81% if I want to min-max my chances of passing because after that the gains are lower and my time would be spent less efficiently.

**Optional - finding the exact value of the elbow/knees using the second derivative of the function**

In my example, the "knees" are at 61* and 81, as calculated using the second derivative method. Here I plotted the second derivative (plot the "change" column against the pre-test scores, then plot the derivative of *that*). The 1st knee will be the hight point, the 2nd knee will be the lowest point:

[image: Second derivative of example]

This means that the association of the pre-test score and post-test success probability becomes stronger somewhere around 61%, and becomes weaker at about 81%. One could imagine that if the pre-test grades were able to vary to infinity, the link between the two variables would tend to be non-existent (the line would be flat). There isn't really a specific spot where the association beween the variables became null.

The 81 point is just the place where the  curvature is the most pronounced, so that if you really had to identify a spot where there was an decrease/increase in correlation, the elbow might be it.

*61 may not be the real, "ideal" lower elbow, it could be an artifact resulting from the fact that my data in truncated at 60.